# Singleton in C++ 11 using member function specifiers

Tags: c++11, vector, singleton

I'm aware of the [issues with the Singleton Pattern](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/), but I wanted to use an exercise in creating a Singleton using C++11 member function specifiers to learn about C++11.

Anyway, I got this far:

```
#include<new>
#include<vector>

class Singleton
{
    private:
        Singleton() = default; 
        ~Singleton() = default; 

    public: 

        Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;  
        Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;

        void* operator new(std::size_t) = delete;
        void* operator new[](std::size_t) = delete;

        void operator delete(void*) = delete;
        void operator delete[](void*) = delete;

        static const Singleton& getInstance()
        {
            static Singleton mySingleton;

            return mySingleton; 
        }
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const Singleton& s1 = Singleton::getInstance(); 

    // Why does this compile?
    std::vector<Singleton> v1; 
    // Or this?
    std::vector<Singleton> v2(50); 


    return 0;
}
```

And my question is, why do these lines:

```
std::vector<Singleton> v1; 

std::vector<Singleton> v2(50);
```

compile, and not report an error of a default Singleton constructor being in a private context?

I am using gcc 4.8.2 on a 64bit Linux machine, and the code compiles [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php) as well.

Comment: +1. I was about to say it's because the vector is empty, but it [doesn't seem to be the case](http://ideone.com/QEe5SN).

Comment: I edited the question and added a size constructor.

Comment: This is [GCC bug# 56429](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56429), supposedly a duplicate of [GCC bug# 54812](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54812) which is marked "FIXED".

Comment: Clarification: it was fixed in late October, so the fix hasn't yet made it to a release of GCC.

Comment: Notably, [clang trunk rejects this code at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68875700b79891f5).

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not use the default constructor of Singleton outside of getInstance, since the vector is empty.

Comment: I thought the same, but then I created [this example](http://ideone.com/QEe5SN) and the beast still compiles!

Comment: I think that the version with size constructor should not compile.

Comment: That's actually the OP's question - why *does* it compile?

Comment: It compiles on my machine.

Comment: Interesting thing: it does not compile if the default constructor has an empty body instead of being = default. I thought that one of the main points of "=default" was to be able to control visibility... Maybe we have a compiler bug here?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Visual C++ 2013 have similar behavior, i.e. compile with `default` constructor and do not with empty body one.